# How do I send JSON data to client from a file?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json, http

When this URL is loaded by a HTML file: "http://localhost:8080/load_json?filename=a.json"
I want that HTML file to be able to read the JSON data using javascript. The HTML file is independent from the node.js server.

This is my code:

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var q = url.parse(req.url, true);

  switch(q.pathname) {
  case '/save_json':
    fs.writeFile(q.query.filename, q.query.content, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    }); 
    break;

  case '/load_json':
    fs.readFile(q.query.filename, 'utf8', function(err, data){ 
      
    // Display the file content 
    res.write(data); 
}); 
    break;
} 
  res.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

a.json:

```
a
```

(temporary placeholder)

When I open that URL in my web browser it is completely blank.

Comment: You're running `res.end()` _before_ `res.write()` due to the async `fs.readFile()`.